# wxPython adding custom font from file

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, wxwidgets

First of all I drawing text with *GraphicsContext* and want to import and change font from file (ttf) which is in my project folder.
Thank you

Comment: are you planning to install this font on the customer machine?

Comment: @Igor this app will be running on my raspberry and now I using windows so I think to keep font files with my app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no functionality for adding fonts from external files in wxWidgets currently. Someone contributed code for doing this quite some time ago and it was almost ready for being merged, see http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13568, but this has never happened. If anybody needs this feature badly enough, I hope it might get done in the future.

Comment: looks like they updated the ticket, it's now supported by wxWidgets, but hasn't been incorporated into wxPython

Comment: But how do i use it ??